# is it possible to create List inside our App?

Tags: sharepoint

is it possible to create List and Library inside our App (SharePoint Hosted/ Provider Hosted App), that List/Library should not come into Site Content Gallery?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when your list has been created, you can use the 'Hidden' property on the list item to hide it from site contents

**Powershell:**

```
$webSite = Get-SPWeb "http://SharePoint Site";
$list = $webSite.Lists["TestList"];
$list.Hidden = 1;
$list.Update();
```

Comment: actually i am trying to create a provider hosted app on in SharePoint online, and there i have created a list with three column, but seems like after deploy list is not creating..could you provide some link how to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when using app model (SharePoint Hosted or Provider Hosted App), you probably need to use CSOM in js or C#

Comment: not using app model, but you can if you use farm solutions

Comment: take a look C# csom approach of creating list: https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Commands/Lists/NewList.cs